# Is there any way to use GSON library with Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

Spring Roo by default uses `flexJSON` which is probably not suitable for some issues.

Is there anyway to use `GSON` instead (expect the hard coding part) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it.

Now, I can see to ways to archive it:

1. As you say, make push-in of all JSON related methods and fix it by hand.
2. Create you own Roo Add-on which make it via ITD.

Depending on how many classes you need change (should be too many classes to worth it), the second option could be a good approach (also, then you can share it ;-) ). You can start from [Roo add-on documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html).

Good luck!

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable answer. I believe supporting GSON would be great as a future work. I just have few classes to support :)